# Updating store display PCs

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-powerpoint, external-display

I have 8 PCs that are in our business lobbies that have a PowerPoint file on a constant loop and I want to find the easiest way for a non-admin person to put up a new PowerPoint file from time to time.  A side bonus would to have the computers automatically log in and open the file so we could script the PCs to turn off at night.  The BIOS is configured to return to last power state.

Windows 7
Domain member
Logged is as a local user
wirelessly connected to network

Comment: I would write a simple tool that allowed a user to point to a Power Point file, generate a batch script, and create a Scheduled Task that ran said batch script.  The batch script would always exists, if it wasn't running a selected Power Point file, have it run a different file.  You could also just tell users to give the file a specific name which would be detected automatically.

Comment: I think I'll be ditching powerpoint in favor of www.risevision.com. It's a Chrome based app that can manage my multiple displays and easy enough that I can leave most of the management to the users responsible for updating them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is to have a "Login Script" on each PC for the user logging into the PC.

If this is a Domain PC:
Let the non-admin login to the PC, and then let the login script take over (details below)

If this is a non-domain PC:
You can set auto-login --> run "netplwiz" and untick the "User must enter username and password" and go from there, and again after that let the login script take over.

Login script can be placed here:

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Just for that specific user.

Or if you don't care who is logged in and it will trigger the logon script, you place the script here:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Sample code/idea (for a .bat file):

```
REM Connect to Network Server
net use X: \\SERVER\Share
REM Copy the file locally (so the file is not 'locked' on the network share)
copy /Y X:\path\to\ppt\myppt.ppt C:\temp\
REM Open Powerpoint (which already set to run in a kiosk mode unattended in a loop)
c:\temp\myppt.ppt
```

Now the server can be any PC that your non-admin have access to or just a share folder that your non-admin can have full access. They can simply throw a new PPT file in there, and at the next login (or forced restart) then the 8 PCs can get the new PPT the next time they boot up and someone logged in.

From here you have 2 options:

1. Let the non-admin restart all 8 PCs remotely (use a batch script similar to below, but you need to prepare the correct access level for the non-admin)
2. Get the non-admin to contact you/other admin, and you can restart the PC remotely.

And that batch file for restarting the PC can have something like:

```
shutdown /m \\PC01 /r /t 1 
.....
shutdown /m \\PC08 /r /t 1
```

Note: restart the remote PC in 1 second.

About the PC turning off at night.. you can use similar script just change /r with /s for shutdown.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you think they are able to edit a batch file in Notepad, and they know how to reference a (.ppt) file somewhere in your network, place two shortcuts on the desktop:

- One to edit a START.BAT file in Notepad (give it a useful name like 'Change Powerpoint presentation')
- One to execute that START.BAT ('Start Powerpoint presentation')

Place the START.BAT file in a network directory, so that it can be changed from any one of the 8 PCs.

Add the START.BAT file to the startup folder of each of the PCs.

You can even put instructions in the batch file like:

REM Change the below name of the PowerPoint file to switch to another presentation

You could even write the batch file to concatenate a folder name and a file name, so that all they have to change is the file name.

There's one thing I cannot figure out yet - if anyone knows it please edit my answer - and that's how to restart the other 7 PCs after the change...